# How to fire every 2 day of the month?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, laterjs

I am using later.js in my node.js backend and I want to start a function on every second day of every month. How can I parse this (if someone knows in cron syntax would be also helpful)

Comment: When you tried to learn cron syntax, what was the problem you encountered? Have you checked the [later.js documentation](https://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html)? Is there anything you tried? It is literally `later.parse.text('on the 2nd day of the month')`.

Comment: I have tried this ```later.parse.text("every second day of the month")``` but it was incorrect. Your solution helped me, thank you

Comment: Putting in what you tried that didn't work is a huge part of a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the chron expression to run every second day of the month, At 00:00 See the [link](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_2_*_*)

```
0 0 2 * *
```

Comment: Your solution is also correct, thank you